How to create a delay between two user interface events updates in JavaFX?
I've been trying to code tetris with JavaFX, and while the logic of the game works, I've been struggling with an issue.
For this project, I'm modeling the blocks with Rectangle shapes; I move these rectangle shapes with methods setLayoutX and setLayoutY, and I use scene.setOnKeyPressed method to take user keyboard inputs. I'm using an AnimationTimer to run the game loop. So far, so good, but...
As we all know, in the game of tetris, when a row is filled, it is eliminated and all blocks above that row move down. I want to highlight the filled row before I eliminate it. I want to change the color of the blocks in the filled row, then delay the execution for say half second, and only then eliminate the blocks of the filled row.
I have no idea how to implement the delay.
I have already tried (a) to create new Thread and use Platform.runLater, (b) Task, (c) while loop but none of it works. I'll leave part of the code I'm dealing with here:
/* some code above */
if(isFilledRow) {
    for(int j=0;j<nCol;j++) {
        for(int k=0;k<blocks.size();k++) {
            BlockUnit bu=blocks.get(k);
            if(bu.getY()==i && bu.getX()==j) {
                bu.getShape().setFill(Color.BROWN);
            }
        }
    }
        /* the delay should happen here */
    for(int j=0;j<nCol;j++) {
        for(int k=0;k<blocks.size();k++) {
            BlockUnit bu=blocks.get(k);
            if(bu.getY()==i && bu.getX()==j) {
                blocks.remove(bu);
                root.getChildren().remove(bu.getShape());
            }
        }
    }
}
/* some code below */


I think you can use the javafx's Timeline for this.
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/* some code above */
if (isFilledRow) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < blocks.size(); k++) {
            BlockUnit bu = blocks.get(k);
            if (bu.getY() == i && bu.getX() == j) {
                bu.getShape().setFill(Color.BROWN);
            }
        }
    }
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500),
            e -> {
                for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < blocks.size(); k++) {
                        BlockUnit bu = blocks.get(k);
                        if (bu.getY() == i && bu.getX() == j) {
                            blocks.remove(bu);
                            root.getChildren().remove(bu.getShape());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }));
    timeline.play();
}
/* some code below */


You can make the blocks aware of their state and responsible for eliminating themselves.
To initiate an elimination, all the caller needs to do is invoke an eliminate() method on the block.
Once they are marked for elimination, the blocks block any further user input to themselves, change their color to the elimination color, and wait for a PauseTransition to complete the elimination duration, after which they remove themselves from the scene.
In this example, the blocks get eliminated by clicking on them. You could instead ask them to be eliminated as part of your update method in your animation timer, by invoking the eliminate method on appropriate blocks when you determine they should be eliminated.
Various other kinds of transitions (e.g. fade transitions, fill transitions, sprite animations), could be used instead of a plain pause if additional visual effects are required.  This cat whack application uses a similar concept.
Block.java
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.effect.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.util.Duration;

class Block {
    public static final double BLOCK_SIZE = 40;
    private static final Color ELIMINATED_COLOR = Color.PURPLE;
    private static final Duration ELIMINATION_DURATION = Duration.seconds(.5);
    private static final Effect HOVER_EFFECT = new Glow();

    private final Rectangle shape = new Rectangle(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
    private final PauseTransition eliminationTransition = new PauseTransition(ELIMINATION_DURATION);

    public Block(Paint paint) {
        shape.setFill(paint);
        shape.setStrokeWidth(2);
        shape.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);
        shape.hoverProperty().addListener((observable, wasHovered, isHovered) -> {
            shape.setEffect(isHovered ? HOVER_EFFECT : null);
            shape.setStroke(isHovered ? Color.GOLD : null);
        });

        eliminationTransition.setOnFinished(e -> {
            Group shapeParent = (Group) shape.getParent();
            if (shapeParent != null) {
                shapeParent.getChildren().remove(shape);
            }
        });
    }

    public void eliminate() {
        shape.setFill(ELIMINATED_COLOR);
        shape.setMouseTransparent(true);
        eliminationTransition.play();
    }

    public Shape getShape() {
        return shape;
    }
}

BlockApp.java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class BlockApp extends Application {
    private static final double GRID_SIZE = 4;
    private static final Color INDIA_INK = Color.web("#3C3F4A");
    private final List<Color> palette = List.of(Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW);

    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Group grid = new Group();
        addBlocks(grid);

        grid.getChildren().addListener((ListChangeListener<Node>) c -> {
            if (grid.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
                addBlocks(grid);
            }
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(grid, INDIA_INK));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void addBlocks(Group grid) {
        for (int row = 0; row < GRID_SIZE; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < GRID_SIZE; col++) {
                Block block = new Block(colorBlock(row, col));
                block.getShape().relocate(col * Block.BLOCK_SIZE, row * Block.BLOCK_SIZE);
                block.getShape().setOnMouseClicked(e -> block.eliminate());
                grid.getChildren().add(block.getShape());
            }
        }
    }

    private Color colorBlock(int row, int col) {
        Color rowColor = palette.get(row % palette.size());
        Color rowStartColor = rowColor.deriveColor(0, 1, 1, .3);

        return rowStartColor.interpolate(rowColor, col / GRID_SIZE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

